# how to implement move object using animation when in touch in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a case, when we touch an object let's say a textview, then the object reactions after I touch it moved to another layout, I have a case example on a video on youtube, here is a youtube video url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyhtRr3y_7U. From the video, the app uses what method to move such an object?
please help me to solve this case. I'm deadlocked thinking about what method they use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single method to perform all these animations, Android gives you flexibility to perform a lot of animations and they have provided helper classes as well but you will have to figure out how and where to use them. To make an app like the one in video you will have to combine a lot of animations. You can start reading about ObjectAnimator, ValueAnimator, SharedElementTranistion, SceneTransition. Here are some tutorials which you can check out

https://www.raywenderlich.com/173345/android-animation-tutorial-with-kotlin

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-animations-android-transition-framework-part-1/

http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-1/

Comment: I'm still confused to move the view to another view using transitions. Is there any reference to this case?